# How to add a button on certain woocomerce products

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I would like to add a button with a custom link on certain woocommerce products.

I partially solved the problem by adding this code :

```
 jQuery(function($) {
   $('.woocommerce .product_meta ').after ('<a class="button" href="http://www.ekosport.fr/N1-GL3357-community-touring-club.html">Acheter sur Ekosport</a>');
 });
```

But I would like to add a condition : the button should be hidden on the product category "Textile CTC"

Here is an example of a product : 
https://communitytouringclub.com/produit/t-shirt-ctc/

Thanks for helping

PS : the jquery code is not activated for now

Comment: Have you tried to hide this button using code? If you have, please include that code in your example. A *sample* of the html you are using would be helpful as well (in other words, just enough html to help - not the whole page :) )

Comment: Thank you for the idea.

I finaly solved my problem by adding some extra css with a page id prefixe to hide the button

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) on your `.product_meta` selection to check if the text contents of the child `.posted_in > a` matches a string such as `"Textile CTC"`.

Then only insert the button markup using [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to the filtered selection.

```js
const matchText = "Textile CTC";

$(function() {
  $(".product_meta")
    .filter(function() {
      return (
        $(this).find(".posted_in > a").text() === matchText
      );
    })
    .after(
      '<a class="button" href="http://www.ekosport.fr/N1-GL3357-community-touring-club.html">Acheter sur Ekosport</a>'
    );
});
```

```css
.button {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product_meta">
  <span class="sku_wrapper">UGS&nbsp;: 2018-men-CTC-t-shirt-1</span>
  <span class="posted_in">Catégorie&nbsp;:
      <a href="https://communitytouringclub.com/categorie-produit/textile-ctc/" rel="tag">Textile CTC</a>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="product_meta">
  <span class="sku_wrapper">UGS&nbsp;: 2018-men-CTC-t-shirt-1</span>
  <span class="posted_in">Catégorie&nbsp;:
      <a href="https://communitytouringclub.com/categorie-produit/textile-ctc/" rel="tag">Somthing else</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea.

I finaly solved my problem by adding some extra css with a page id prefixe to hide the button